# Auto dismissal of remote/local notification in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

There is a default 5 second time to auto-dismiss the remote/local notification in iOS 10. Is there a way to programatically make it not getting auto-dismissed and need user interaction (swipe up action) to dismiss.

So, the behaviour would be similar to choosing notification type as "Alert" via Settings in iOS 10.

Anyone has done this before or have any idea about it?